# More Columns than Column Names?

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a file that has 24 column headers, but 14 additional null values. See link: https://www.elections.il.gov/ElectionInformation/CandDataFile.aspx?id=51

Whenever I run the code below, I get the message

> "more columns than column names."

I feel like the answer is probably simple. Any idea?

```
candidates <- read.csv(file = "candidates.txt", sep = ",", 
                        header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: It would help if you post the data. Please take a look at this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example 
Also, I cant open the link you provided.

Answer (score 11):

One solution is to read the headers only with one command, the data without header in a second, and then delete excess columns and set the names.

```
NAMES <- read.table("candidates.txt", nrow = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
DATA <- read.table("candidates.txt", skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
DATA <- DATA[, 1:24]
names(DATA) <- NAMES
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while running through docker. So, I had to download the file first then read csv file.

```
# download data
download.file("https://www.elections.il.gov/ElectionInformation/CandDataFile.aspx?id=51", dest = "candidates.txt")

# load data
gm = read.table("candidates.txt", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, skipNul = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and I think the issue was with the header. Because when I deleted the header (a line beginning with a '#' at the beginning of the file), no error would occur. At last, the solution in the link below solved the problem. It sets the parameter 'skip' to 1 to skip the first line of the file (the header).

[https://community.rstudio.com/t/more-columns-than-column-names-error/43517](https://community.rstudio.com/t/more-columns-than-column-names-error/43517/4)

Comment: this is not an answer. Link-only answers and "i faced the same problem" posts are not considered answers and should be removed.